# Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type for child classes

Tags: c#, casting, language-design

The following code gives the error in the title on the second line in the Main function.

```
public class P {}

public class B : P {}

public class A : P {}

void Main()
{   
    P p = GetA()??GetB();
}

public A GetA() 
{
    return new A();
}

public B GetB()
{
    return new B();
}
```

A simple tweak to the line like these

```
    p = (P)GetA()??GetB();
    or
    p = GetA()??(P)GetB();
```

works.

I'm curious why the compiler doesn't understand that both are child classes of the left hand side container and allow the operation without the cast?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of the argument on the left hand side must be compatible with the type on the right hand side or vice versa.  In other words, there must exist an implicit conversion from `B` to `A` or from `A` to `B`.

```
var a = x ?? y;
```

In the above, if there is an implicit conversion from `y` to `x` then the type of `x` becomes the type of the expression.  if there is no implicit conversion from `y` to `x`, but there is an implicit conversion from `x` to `y`, then the type of `y` becomes the type of the expression.  if no conversion exists in either direction, boom; compilation error.  From the spec:

> The type of the expression a ?? b depends on which implicit conversions are available between the types of the operands. In order of preference, the type of a ?? b is A0, A, or B, where A is the type of a, B is the type of b (provided that b has a type), and A0 is the underlying type of A if A is a nullable type, or A otherwise. Specifically, a ?? b is processed as follows:
>
> •  If A is not a nullable type or a reference type, a compile-time error occurs.
>
> •  If A is a nullable type and an implicit conversion exists from b to A0, the result type is A0. At run-time, a is first evaluated. If a is not null, a is unwrapped to type A0, and this becomes the result. Otherwise, b is evaluated and converted to type A0, and this becomes the result.
>
> •  Otherwise, if an implicit conversion exists from b to A, the result type is A. At run-time, a is first evaluated. If a is not null, a becomes the result. Otherwise, b is evaluated and converted to type A, and this becomes the result.
>
> •  Otherwise, if b has a type B and an implicit conversion exists from A0 to B, the result type is B. At run-time, a is first evaluated. If a is not null, a is unwrapped to type A0 (unless A and A0 are the same type) and converted to type B, and this becomes the result. Otherwise, b is evaluated and becomes the result.
>
> •  Otherwise, a and b are incompatible, and a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: Ahh I see, I was in the process of writing a very involved comment when I re-read your example and realised that the type of the LHS is derived from the evaluation of the expression on the RHS. Initially, I thought as long as both `x` and `y` can convert to `a` then it's all good!

Comment: Yeah, including the type of the variable being assigned to is the most straight forward way and exactly how I would have thought it would work at first.  I would love to hear from someone like Eric Lippert on this as to why it was designed this way.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm curious why the compiler doesn't understand that both are child classes of the left hand side container and allow the operation without the cast?

Because then this would be allowed:

```
public class SqlConnection : object {}    
public class Random : object {}

public SqlConnection GetA() { return new SqlConnection(); }
public Random GetB() { return new Random(); }

void Main()
{   
    var p = GetA() ?? GetB();
}
```

Comment: hum... but hang on! `var p = (object)GetA() ?? GetB();` is allowed. It may be syntactically different but achieves the same logical purpose.

Comment: @Joe: You can cast anything to object, and since there is an implicit conversion from B to object the resultant expression will return object. Using var here hurts the example as p will be of type object should you perform the cast.

Comment: @Ed, i'm really confused about what you mean. if I intend that p can be either a SqlConnection or a Random, then the above code is  legitimate. However, the syntax/rule of the `??` operator is stopping me from doing so. Basically, i think i'm saying, if i think it's ok for p to be an object, then this example doesn't show why it can't be... because a simple cast gives me what i want

Comment: But it doesn't give you what you want; the return type would be object.  You would have to perform another cast to get a specific type that you can use.

Comment: Well, in the original example, ideally the parent would have a property common to both child and so i didn't really care which one was not null as long as one of them was, so i could do p.CommonVariable. so in my scenario, it does get me what i want and type casting it is just a 'workaround'?

Answer (score -1):

the operands of the operator ?? should be of same type:

```
    P a = GetA();
    P b = GetB();
    P p = a ?? b;
```

Comment: They don't have to be the same type, there simply must exist an *implicit conversion* from one to the other.