# Casting to different types with the conditional operator

Tags: c#, operators, conditional-statements

I am trying to check whether my object info is either a word.Selection or a word.Document and then use it later in my program.

Here is where I am getting some trouble.

```
 object info;
 var doc = info is word.Document ? info as word.Document : info as word.Selection;
 //do something with doc.Words;
```

It returns this error:

> *Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is
>   no implicit conversion between
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document' and
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection'*

I can't seem to get around this error

Comment: In general, using the `is` operator followed by using the `as` operator or casting is a code smell - if you want to try to cast, try to cast, this `is` operator is useful when you *don't* actually want to cast.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `?:` operator the two results must be of the same type.

Use a standard if case:

```
if(info is word.Document)
{
    //your code
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way I can use to work with either the word.Document or word.Selection?
Using an if statement would lead me to doubling my code.

Comment: @ismellike: try this `var doc = info as word.Document ?? info as word.Selection`. The `as` conversion will return `null` if the conversion fails and the null coalescing operator will execute the second part if the previous value is `null`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel +1 Nice one. Have you thought of writing an answer? It could be as well the one the OP is looking for.

Comment: I have added it as an answer below.

Comment: I have deleted my answer. As you can see in this answer, an implicit conversion has to be available between the two types in order to do this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829903/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-for-child-classes

Answer (score 2):

From [`?: Operator (C# Reference)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ty67wk28.aspx)

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the
>   same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

In your first expression returns `word.Document`, but second returns `word.Selection`. Since they are not the same, but also looks like there is no implicit conversation between them.